# hierarchial clustering for gene expression in r

Tags: r

I have a RMA normalized genes expression datset with 22810 rows and 9 columns( types of promoters) and a subset of the data is as follows:

```
ID_REF GSM362180    GSM362181  GSM362188    GSM362189  GSM362192
244901 5.094871713 4.626623079 4.554272515 4.748604391 4.759221647
244902 5.194528083 4.985930299 4.817426064 5.151654407 4.838741605
244903 5.412329253 5.352970877 5.06250609  5.305709079 8.365082403
244904 5.529220594 5.28134657  5.467445095 5.62968933  5.458388909
244905 5.024052699 4.714631878 4.792865831 4.843975286 4.657188246
244906 5.786557533 5.242403911 5.060605782 5.458148567 5.890061836
```

I want to do a clustering of the above and tried the hierarchical clustering:

```
d <- dist(as.matrix(deg), method = "euclidean")
```

where deg is the a matrix of the differentially expressed genes ( 4300 in number ).And I get the following warning:

```
  Warning message:
 In dist(as.matrix(deg), method = "euclidean") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Is it allright to proceed with the clustering inspite of the warning ?

```
hc <- hclust(d)
plot(hc, hang = -0.01, cex = 0.7)
```

I get a dendrogram which is very dense and the labels are not clear: Also I do not know which of the 9 promoters are classified in the tree for the several genes: How would it be possible to label the tree with the promoters and also how to visualize the genes into a clearer dendrogram? Iam not sure how I have to add the dendrogram here else I would .

Comment: How would it be possible to reproduce the whole data here?

Comment: Yes, I tried doing for both 20 and uptil 500 I still get the same error.

Comment: I have exactly tried with the same one(for 6 rows and 5 columns) that I have posted in the question and still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment, I can't reproduce your error. I read in the data:

```
##Read in the data
deg = read.table(textConnection("ID_REF GSM362180    GSM362181  GSM362188    GSM362189  GSM362192
244901 5.094871713 4.626623079 4.554272515 4.748604391 4.759221647
244902 5.194528083 4.985930299 4.817426064 5.151654407 4.838741605
244903 5.412329253 5.352970877 5.06250609  5.305709079 8.365082403
244904 5.529220594 5.28134657  5.467445095 5.62968933  5.458388909
244905 5.024052699 4.714631878 4.792865831 4.843975286 4.657188246
244906 5.786557533 5.242403911 5.060605782 5.458148567 5.890061836"), header=TRUE)
```

I can then calculate the distance matrix:

```
R> dist(as.matrix(deg), method = "euclidean")
      1     2     3     4     5
2 1.173                        
3 4.266 3.701                  
4 3.423 2.288 3.120            
5 4.011 3.038 4.312 1.814      
6 5.282 4.204 3.912 2.109 1.957
```

Comment: I think I made the error in reading in the data. Thank you very much.

Comment: Because you didn't provide an easy way to import your data so copying it into a string and then telling R that it's a piece of text and it should parse it properly is about the easiest way to get your data.  You can [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info on how to make a good reproducible example.